# I have an array of objects. Each object contains max and min key value pairs. How do I find the object that contains a predefined value?

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have an array of insurance rates that looks like this

```
const insuranceRate = [
{
    "min_value": 1,
    "max_value": 25000,
    "add": 328
}, {
    "min_value": 25001,
    "max_value": 25500,
    "add": 331
}, {
    "min_value": 25501,
    "max_value": 26000,
    "add": 335
}, {
    "min_value": 26001,
    "max_value": 26500,
    "add": 338
}]
```

Let's say I purchase a car at $25,900. How to I find the right object and add $335 to my insurance cost ?

Comment: Find the value by using [`Array.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find). `const rate = insuranceRate.find((ir) => ir.minValue <= value && ir.maxValue >= value);`. Then apply that add value. `25900 + rate.add`

Comment: It would be great if you could show any attempts you've made at solving the problem yourself, and show the results of any research you've done while making those attempts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go

```
 const insuranceRate = [
   {
    "min_value": 1,
    "max_value": 25000,
    "add": 328
   }, {
    "min_value": 25001,
    "max_value": 25500,
    "add": 331
   }, {
    "min_value": 25501,
    "max_value": 26000,
    "add": 335
   }, {
    "min_value": 26001,
    "max_value": 26500,
    "add": 338
   }];
   var price=25900;

   var filter=insuranceRate.filter(i=>price >= i.min_value && price <= 
   i.max_value);
   console.log("Result:",filter);
```

Comment: Thanks, I used .find() but .filter() is also correct in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Thats pretty simple, have an for loop  go through every element and check if ur value is inbetween the min and max values the function would look something like that:

```
function F(value){
    for( i=0;i<insuranceRate.length;i++){
        if ( value >= insuranceRate[i].min_value  && value <= insuranceRate[i].max_value){
            return insuranceRate[i];
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

which returns the element within the range, which u then can use to get your add value, also if ur value  is not between the range, it'll return -1

Answer (score 1):

If you want the one with the lowest price I'd go with this:

```
var valid_rates = []; 
insuranceRate.forEach((item, index)=>{ 
    if (price >= item.min_value &&  price <= item.max_value) { 
        valid_rates.push(item.add) ;
    }
}) ;

// Lowest price
Math.min(valid_rates) ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Loop over the aray and check whether your car cost is in the range, if so  - add it to the insurance cost - in this example I initialized it with 0:

```
var my_car = 25900;
var insuranceCost = 0;
for (var i=0; i<insuranceRate.length; i++) {
    if (my_car >= insuranceRate[i].min_value && 
        my_car <= insuranceRate[i].max_value) {
           insuranceCost += insuranceRate[i].add;
    }
} 

console.log(insuranceCost); //335
```